# Making a class generate another class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Okay, so I have an assignment for a class that requires us to use a series of classes together, to simulate a police officer issuing a ticket.

Here's how it works:

ParkedCar class:

To know the cars make, model, color, license number, and the number of minutes
that the car has been parked

ParkingMeter Class:

know how much time has been purchased

ParkingTicket Class:

know make, model, color, license of the car, calculate the fine, as well as the name and badge number of the officer issuing the ticket

PoliceOfficer Class:

Know the name a badge number of the officer

AND

Examine ParkedCar and ParkingMeter objects and determine if a ticket is needed, if so, generate a ParkingTicket object.

Here's what code I have so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

class ParkedCar
{
    string sMake;
    string sModel;
    string sColor;
    string sPlate;
    int iMinsParked;

    public:

    ParkedCar();

    string getMake() const
    { return sMake; }

    void setMake(string temp)
    { sMake = temp; }

    string getModel() const
    { return sModel; }

    void setModel(string temp)
    { sModel = temp; }

    string getColor() const
    { return sColor; }  

    void setColor(string temp)
    { sColor = temp; }

    string getPlate() const
    { return sPlate; }

    void setPlate(string temp)
    { sPlate = temp; }

    int getMins() const
    { return iMinsParked; }

};

ParkedCar::ParkedCar()
{


    srand(time(NULL));

    iMinsParked = (rand() % 10000); 
}

class ParkingMeter
{
    int iMinsPurch;

    public:

    void setMins(int temp)
    { iMinsPurch = temp; }

    int getMins() const
    { return iMinsPurch; }
}

class Ticket : public ParkedCar
{

    public:

    string getName()
    { return sName; }

    int getBadge()
    { return iBadge; }
};

class Officer
{
    string sName;
    int iBadge;

    public:

    friend string Ticket::getName();
    //{ return sName; }

    friend int Ticket::getBadge();
    //{ return iBadge; }
};

int main()
{
    ParkedCar Park;

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << Park.getMins();

    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Where I'm confused is mostly on the Ticket and Officer classes.  The assignment clearly wants Ticket to have it's own information from all the other classes, but I'm not sure how to pass that information along.  I've tried making it a child class of ParkedCar, but I just get a multiple definitions error.  And I can't get the friend functions to work.  I've tried them both ways and if I make them within Ticket, it tells me Officer isn't defined.  And I'm really confused on how I'm supposed to write code for Officer generating an instance of Ticket when nothing has actually been initialized yet.

So:

1. How do I get all the information into the Ticket class?
2. How would I get Officer to generate an instance of Ticket?

Please keep in mind this is a STUDENT assignment, not something professional.  I just want to do what the assignment says.  I'm not interested in ways "around" the problem, because that's not what the prof wants.

Thanks in advance for your time. :D

Comment: For the `Officer` to generate an instance of `Ticket`, he just needs a method with a `Ticket` return type.  Instead of `int` or `string` or `void`, mark the return type as `Ticket`, have the method build and return a `Ticket` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: learn to use constructors.  All this stuff you're setting...it is integral to the identity of a car, or a cop, etc.  It should have been provided when the object was built.  C++ isn't Java; quit treating classes like Java beans. :P

Secondly, a Ticket is not a ParkedCar.  It *associates* with a car, but is not one itself.  Consider instead:

```
class Ticket {
    ParkedCar violator;
    Officer issuer;
  public:
    Ticket(const Officer &cop, const ParkedCar &car) :
        violator(car), issuer(cop) {
    }

    ParkedCar getCar() { return violator; }
    Officer getOfficer() { return issuer; }

    // Note, no mutators here!
    // The biggest reason you had to have mutators, is that your construction
    // was incomplete.
    // The info associated with a Ticket should not be modified once the ticket
    // is written. And since the constructor has all the info needed, there's no
    // need to provide a way to modify them.
};
```

So an Officer doesn't need to know about the potentially-intricate details of a car, or exactly what info a Ticket needs.  He can just hand himself and the car over to the constructor, and trust that it will extract whatever info it needs.  (In this case, we just store copies of both items.)

```
class Officer {
    std::string name;
    int badge_number;

  public:
    Officer(const std::string& name, int badge) : name(name), badge_number(badge) { }

    public std::string getName() { return name; }
    public int getBadgeNumber() { return badge_number; }

    Ticket writeTicketFor(const ParkedCar &violator) {
       return Ticket(*this, violator);
    }
};
```

Comment: Well the prof wants user input for all the car info, so I can't pack all that neatly into a constructor, which is why I have so many mutators.  But I still don't quite understand how to implement your code....whichever class I do, I'm declaring an instance of a class that hasn't been defined yet.

Also, since the car info has to be user defined, I don't understand how I can pass it to Ticket before any  of that data has been initialized.

Comment: The car already exists.  If it didn't, the cop wouldn't know it was parked illegally, and there'd be no ticket to write.  :P  As far as the user input for the car, get the input and then build a car.

Comment: The circularity is a little bit of an issue.  But it can be resolved by saying `class Ticket; class ParkedCar;` in the header file for the `Officer` class.  C++ lets you use incomplete types in function declarations, and an officer doesn't need to contain an object of either type, so all should be good once the code's moved out to its own .cpp files.  (In the .cpp file, you'd include the headers for those classes.)

Comment: I gotta be honest, I have no idea how your code is supposed to work. :C  We only recently learned about passing information between classes using the friend declaration.  And here you're telling me to hand whole classes over to constructors?  I have absolutely no idea how to do that properly, or what any other of the 20 functions in your code are supposed to be.  I just need a simple, dummy-proof way to do this. XD

Comment: Okay, I'm seeing how using a constructor for Ticket when Officer creates it makes sense.  But I don't understand how I'm suppose to pass in the data from all the other classes to Ticket without using all those accessors.

Comment: If you insist on setting fields within Ticket, then use the getters.  But you don't need any of the setters; `Ticket::Ticket` (or `Ticket::getMake` etc)  can pull data from the car and officer as needed.

Comment: Ah, I think I see.  Because the classes are taken as arguments to the constructor.  Well, the instructions for the lab sound like the prof wants Ticket to actually HOLD the data, so I guess I have to use the setters.  Nonetheless, many thanks for the help. :D

Comment: If a Ticket contains a ParkedCar and Officer, both members' data are actually part of the class. It *does* hold the data, just indirectly. You can expose the fields like (eg:) `string getPlate() { return violator.getPlate(); }`. This is encapsulation -- *real* encapsulation, not that fakey-fake blindly-get-and-set-a-backing-variable stuff. :)  And with full construction, you never once have to say `ticket.setPlate(...);`. A fully-constructed ParkedCar, if it exists, definitely has a valid plate. A bean-style ParkedCar, on the other hand, might not have been completely configured.

Comment: (Note, "definitely has a valid plate" assumes that you are validating the data before setting it.  You should be doing that regardless, and could even do the validation via a setter if you really want mutability.  But at the very least, you know the creator had to have set it to something.)